# How to suppress table headers completely in jQuery DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTables plugin (www.datatables.net) for jQuery to display tables on a web page.

After reading through the documentation and doing some searches, I am unable to find out how to completely suppress or hide table headers, using the DataTables options or API.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Why don't you simply hide them through css (i think datatables requires a thead section to work)?

```
.dataTables_wrapper table thead{
    display:none;
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LhZF3/

Comment: Thank you. Messing with the DOM/CSS is not the most elegant solution, but at least it works :-)

Comment: Works great, but still it is very weird that the API itself won't expose such functionality.

Answer (score 15):

I know the question is pretty old, but I searched for it today and found another solution ...

In your js / coffee file:

```
$("#selector").dataTable({
  ... your other options ...

  fnDrawCallback: -> $("#selector thead").remove()
})
```

Pure JS variant:

```
$("#selector").dataTable({
  ... your other options ...

  fnDrawCallback: function() {
    $("#selector thead").remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: this worked for me - with display:none the table header still influences the body rendering ..

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802753/jquery-datatables-hide-thead

Answer (score 7):

Simple add the style `display:none` inline style to your thead tag.

```
    <thead style="display:none;">
    </thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your css:

```
thead {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Careful.  This will suppress all headers from all tables, regardless of Datatables or not.