# jQuery datatables hide thead

Tags: jquery, datatables

i want to hide datatable thead if table dont have any data.

```
oTable_topics =$('#showTopics').dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 12,                               
    "bScrollCollapse": true,       
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true
    });
    function clickRowHandler_topics() {
        $('#showTopics tbody tr').bind('click', function () {
            var aData = oTable_topics.fnGetData( this );
            iId_topics = aData[1];
        });
    }
```

i think if table dont have any data hiding thead is good for display any message for users, how to hide that?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
    $(oSettings.nTHead).hide();
}
```

["fnDrawCallback" function is called on every 'draw' event, and allows you to dynamically modify any aspect you want about the created DOM.](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnDrawCallback)

Comment: To remove the grid header and footer (the `<div class="row">` before and after `<table>` you can do: `$(oSettings.nTableWrapper.firstChild).hide(); $(oSettings.nTableWrapper.lastChild).hide();`

Comment: It seems that there is another easy method to hide <thead>  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732254/how-to-supress-table-headers-completely-in-jquery-datatables

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but answering for others as this was the top result while I was looking into how to do this.

#### DataTables 1.10 answer

```js
"drawCallback": function() {
  $(this.api().table().header()).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in this option:

```
"sDom": 'rt'
```

it will hide header and footer, but first,you still need to check whether there is return data or not.