# Datatable remove tool bar

Tags: jquery, datatable

how can I remove a tool bar at the top of a datatable? I have tried the dirty way:

```
$(document).load(function() {
  $('.btn-group .float-right .tabletools-topbar').hide();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress table headers completely in jQuery DataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732254/how-to-suppress-table-headers-completely-in-jquery-datatables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`sDom`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom) parameter according to your needs when initializing your datatable.

If you only want a simple table, just do :

```
$('#yourTable').dataTable({
    "sDom": 't'
});
```

Here is a list of allowed options :

- `l` - *Length changing*
- `f` - *Filtering input*
- `t` - *The table!*
- `i` - *Information*
- `p` - *Pagination*
- `r` - *pRocessing*

Comment: and there is a 'T' option for toolbar :) - that it was! :)

Comment: I thinks many things changed since this answer. even by including everything `"sDom": 'Tlftipr'` table looks weird and out of shape. even styles are not applied.

Comment: reading through code comments I noticed that this is mostly used for ordering the elements in the container with lfrtip being default. however setting it to `lfrtip` still didn't render the table correctly.