# JQuery Datatable with customized view

Tags: jquery, datatable, dataview

I am looking for a way to modify the structure of JQuery Datatable. What I am looking for is a structure like Dataview than a Datatable in which there wont be headers and it only has one unified column which contains an HTML structure. Something like the way Stackoverflow lists the questions:

[image]

Is this achievable using the Datatable or I have to use another Jquery library?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with DataTables.  There is an option to hide the header row.  There's also an option to specify the number of columns, which in your case would be one.  And finally, you can insert HTML into the table cells.

Comment: That sounds great! I could not find any documentation around this feature though!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732254/how-to-suppress-table-headers-completely-in-jquery-datatables